# Sending request to Secure SSL Server with certificate authentication in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone application for my client in which I have to send requests to a Secure SSL Server(Client's server, everything is ready by server side) with certificate authentication.
I am not getting exact procedure, or exact code showing steps to be followed. (i.e Procedure is not clear to me) 
If anybody can explain me the mechanism behind it, it will be helpful for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to do anything.

Just use proper URL with https://

All the underlying complexity will be handled by NSURLConnection class. It is as same as calling any other network services.

Comment: Hi Apurv, Thank you.
But, To use external web services my client(server side) need to have my certificate (for test it can be even self signed) to be uploaded to gate.